# Rendering mobile and desktop widget view files

Tags: php, yii2

The code below is from the category widget which renders to the widget view index file.

```
class Category extends Widget{         

public function run(){ 

        return $this->render('category/index', [                
       'data' => TreeHelper::makeProductTree(),
    ]);
}
```

}

Now I would like to create another index file for mobile view. But I am having trouble in rendering it. Could you please share your opinion with me how I can render mobile index file as well?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Would you like to render both files at the same time? 
Or do you want to have a flag which indicates what file to render?

Comment: @MaartenvanMiddelaar, thank you for your comment. My opinion was to render both files at the same time. But if indicating with flag is much convenient way then I can try that as well. Please explain how I can make it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be rendering both:

```
class Category extends Widget{         

    public function run()
    { 
        return $this->render('category/index', [                
           'data' => TreeHelper::makeProductTree(),
        ]) . 
        $this->render('category/index-mobile', [                
           'data' => TreeHelper::makeProductTree(),
        ]);
    }
}
```

You could also try

```
class Category extends Widget{         

    public $view = 'category/index';    

    public function run()
    { 
        return $this->render($view, [                
           'data' => TreeHelper::makeProductTree(),
        ]);
    }
}
```

And then calling the widget twice for each like this

`echo Category::widget(['view'=>'category/index']);` or `echo Category::widget();`

and

`echo Category::widget(['view'=>'category/index-mobile']);`

Comment: Thank you very much for your comprehensive answer. I will try the second as well

Comment: I used the first option for rendering. It seems it worked, but I am having some difficulties in calling it for mobile view.  I use the following line for desktop but don't know how for mobile.                                                       <?=  \frontend\widgets\Category::widget();?>

Comment: Do you need both views rendered at the same time, choose option 1. If you need to render the view that is relevant, choose option 2.